# how to bound the number of threads running simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say i've got a list which holds 100 threads inside it.

i want to allow only 5 threads run simultaneously until all my threads in list have done their job.

i also can't use the java threadpool for this task.

could you give me a clue how to bound the number of my running threads?

Comment: Why can't you use an executor service ?

Comment: You can just keep a number lol.

Comment: Why ? What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Re-implement your own threadpool ?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to implement a threadpool my self.

Comment: Its a strange kind of thread pool if it allocates twenty times as many threads as you want to allow to run at the same time.  Why are there 100 threads?  If you only want five threads to run, then why have any more than five threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is [semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Check the doc. 
Briefly speaking, semaphore is a locking method. You ask the resource from the semaphore singleton class, which is process scope unique, control the running number of function process.